# Saving the data from ajax call to a variable in view in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am getting the json data that i am sending to display in a div by append but i want to save that data to a variable so that i can use it even after page reload

here is my code

```
    jQuery('#npost').submit(function(e){

            e.preventDefault();
            var formData = new FormData(this);

            var url= '<?php echo base_url("user/postData"); ?>';

            jQuery.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url:url,
                data: formData,
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(data)
                {
                  var ParsedObject = JSON.stringify(data);

                 var json = $.parseJSON(ParsedObject);
                  alert(json.status);
                var value= json;

                 json.textdata;
                 //$("#status_data").val(json.textdata);

                 $('#result_table').append(json.textdata);



          },
                error: function(data){
                //error function
              }
           });            
        });

here is my controller

public function postData()
  {
    $post = $this->input->post();
    //print_r($post);
    unset($post['submit']);
    $this->load->model('Pmodel');
    $post_data=$this->Pmodel->post_data($post);

   echo json_encode($post);


  }

view

<div id='result_table' style="color:white;">
          <?php echo $status;  ?><br>
        </div>
```

can i save the data in a html element and echo it in the controller or is it possible to save it in the view ?

Comment: you would not able to use jquery variable after page reload .and explain clearly what you want to achieve ?

Comment: created a textarea where if i write something data gets save into the database as well as show in the view page now i want to save that data to a variable and keep it on view page so  the data that i had written would show itself on the page whenever i open the view.

Comment: this is what i want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

In your success function write below code

```
            var json= $.parseJSON( data);
            if( json.success !== undefined ) {
            $("#span_id").text(json.status);
            }
```

In your  view

```
    <div id='result_table' style="color:white;">
    <span id="span_id"></span><br>
    </div>
```